# How to resctrict data in a dataframe by time/date

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I was already looking for an answer, but so far I'm still stuck with this problem. I have to code a location recommendation software based on given data.
The data has following structure:

```
UserID  VenueID CategoryID  CategoryName    Latitude    Longitude   TimezoneOffset  UTCtime
470 49bbd6c0f964a520f4531fe3    4bf58dd8d48988d127951735    Arts & Crafts Store 40.719810375488535  -74.00258103213994  -240    Tue Apr 03 18:00:09 +0000 2012
```

My software will get userID, categoryID and a date as input and the software should only consider data (for the recommendation) up to the given date (yyyy-dd-mm is enough, no hours, minutes etc.)

How can I choose data only until e.g. 2012-04-12? I've seen a lot solutions which make the datetime as index, but while I have 227428 dates only 224653 are unique, so I don't know if this would work.

I have to convert my dateframe entries from string to datetime. This works with pandas.to_datetime, but how do I apply this to my software(e.g. syntax).
This doesn't work obviously:

```
df2 = df[df['UTCtime']<date_input]
```

Thanks for any help and just ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. I separately converted my 'UTCtime' column to datetime object and added it to my dataframe. Then I was able to the restriction. ;)